# i want to return two values from one lambda and assign to the other one but i got error

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I had tried to return values to a and b by using the below method

```
(lambda a,b:print(a,b))((lambda x:(x,[int(i)**len(x) for i in x]))('153'))
```

but this shows error,i need some help to fix this.

```
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Comment: What do you want to archieve? And what is the purpose of the brackets?

Comment: Is there any reason why need you to put all of this into one line, instead of having separate function definitions? Why do you define ``lambda a,b:print(a,b)``, instead of just using ``print`` directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner function returns a single tuple of two values, but the outer function expects two separate values. Use [`*`-unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to have each value of the tuple passed as a separate parameter:

```
#       v takes two parameters     v provides one tuple of two values
(lambda a,b:print(a,b))(*(lambda x:(x,[int(i)**len(x) for i in x]))('153'))
#                       ^ unpack operator
```

Note that `print` already takes positional arguments – `(lambda a,b:print(a,b))` can be replaced by just `print`. Also, Python3.8 introduces the `:=` assignment operator, which can often be used instead of a `lambda` to emulate `let` expressions. This shortens the expression significantly:

```
# v print takes multiple arguments
print(*(x := '153', [int(i)**len(x) for i in x]))
#         ^ assignment operator binds in current scope
```

Answer (score 1):

@MisterMiyagi posted the correct answer using the given structure. However, I can't think of a case where using two lambdas in the way you did would be useful. Defining a function would make the code much more readable:

```
def print_values(string):
    values = [int(i)**len(string) for i in string]
    print(string, values)

print_values("153")
```

Or if you want it shorter:

```
def print_values(string):
    print(string, [int(i)**len(string) for i in string])

print_values("153")
```

Comment: yes ,your answer is more sensible but iam trying to do it in a single line,thank you..anyway.....